# extend a library with own logic / bypass constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor, aop, superagent

I want to add some add some extra logic (logging, trace stuff) into the main function of superagent: https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/blob/master/lib/client.js#L444

So I need to extend superagent, and want to provide the same API, kind of passthrough all functions. I tried to solve it via different mechanisms: Object.create, prototype, deep copy, but I didn't get it working.

I don't want to manipulate the source code of superagent, just require it and wrap it, add my extra logic and call, passthrough the origin function. I think it's kind of aspect oriented.

// edit
So what don't work for me is to bypass the Request constructor:

```
function Request(method, url) {
  var self = this;
  Emitter.call(this);
  this._query = this._query || [];
  this.method = method;
  this.url = url;
  this.header = {};
  this._header = {};
  this.on('end', function(){
    try {
      var res = new Response(self);
      if ('HEAD' == method) res.text = null;
      self.callback(null, res);
    } catch(e) {
      var err = new Error('Parser is unable to parse the response');
      err.parse = true;
      err.original = e;
      self.callback(err);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Please show the (whole) code you've tried, not (only)the original constructor. Also show us *what* extra logic you want to add an *when* that should become active, best with an example invocation of your wrapped constructor and the expected output.

Comment: You can see the whole code (whole file) in the link I provided, the line with the constructor is highlighted.

Comment: But that's the original code, isn't it? I mean the codes from your approaches that didn't work: "*Object.create, prototype, deep copy*" - what did you do? How didn't they work? And without telling us which logic you want to inject, it's not even a real question.

Comment: Ah okay, I just tried `var foo = Object.create(require("superagent"))` for instance. I have some success, I post it as an answer.

Comment: Regarding the former `AOP` tag, wrapping and reassigning already declared functionality (be it functions or methods) misses any aspect of _AOP_. Any language which wants to qualify for the latter has to provide abstraction levels for at least `Joinpoint`, `Advice` and `Aspect`. The use case described by the OP should be referred to as method modification, and JavaScript of cause is well suited for this scenario and could easily provide a complete `target`/`context` aware toolset of method modifiers like `around`, `before`, `after`, `afterThrowing` and `afterFinally` via `Function.prototype`.

Answer (score 1):

I got it almost working with this code:

```
var superagent = require('superagent');
var uuid = require('uuid');

var map = {};

var init = function() {

    var supderdebug = function(method, url) {
        console.log("pass through: root");
        return superagent.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    var methods = ['get', 'head', 'del', 'patch','post', 'put'];
    methods.forEach(function(method) {
        var origin = superagent[method];
        supderdebug[method] = function(url) {
            console.log("pass through: "+method+"('"+url+"')");
            var request = origin.apply(this, arguments);
            var id = uuid();
            map[id] = request;
            return request;
        }

    });

    _end = superagent.Request.prototype.end;
    superagent.Request.prototype.end = function(fn) {
        console.log("pass through: end");
        return _end.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    _callback = superagent.Request.prototype.callback;
    superagent.Request.prototype.callback = function(err, res) {
        console.log("pass through: callback");
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        var response = _callback.apply(this, arguments);
        return response;
    }

    return supderdebug;
}

module.exports.init = init
```

Usage:

```
var sd = require("supderdebug").init();
```

Then I get the same API as superagent provides when I require it: `var superagent = require("superagent")`

But I cannot do the same with the superagent.Request and sa.Response. It doesn't work when I do:

```
superagent.Request.prototype.constructor = function(method, url)
    // my hook
}
```

And there is another side effect, it would be nice if there is a solution without this side effect:

When requiring both my library and superagent, the superagent is not the origin anymore, because I overwrite the functions of superagent.

Answer (score 1):

You need to send in the existing function

```
superagent.Request.prototype.end = function(end) {
  return function() {
      console.log("before end");        
      var request = end.apply(this, arguments);
      console.log("after end");
      return request;
  };
}(superagent.Request.prototype.end);
```

Comment: Hey,  How did you got to know that in superagent Request has send method?